# Which is more natural?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I have just come across the following sentence in Advanced Grammar in Use by Martin Hewings:

> I know you haven't got much time, but if I were you I'd have breakfast before you leave.

Is it only me who feel this sentence is weird? It seems to me that the second "you" in the sentence should be "I":

> I know you haven't got much time, but if I were you I'd have breakfast before I leave.

I'd appreciate it if you could share your thoughts on this.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: If it were written down in a formal essay, one might notice the change in generic pronoun; but why would one ever write any sentence like that in an essay? This is spoken English and in normal speech it simply doesn't matter. Especially in a sentence which comments on the need for speed. The point is that the formal rules are all crutches developed to plaster over the deficiencies of writing in making information clear.

Comment: Both sound a bit unnatural to me.

Comment: The supposition "if I were you" allows the pronouns to be interchanged, because they both refer to the same person in that hypothetical context. Yes, it's kind of weird to switch modes in the middle of the clause, but it's actually pretty natural in this case.

Comment: @John Lawler, Thank you for your comment. I am aware of the difference in written and spoken languages, and especially how flexible the latter can be, but as a leaner of English, I was just curious about how the syntax of the sentence works in this case.

Comment: @Hot Licks, thanks for your response; I was recommended this grammar book because the example sentences are natural, but I realise there is a limit to how natural they could be as is the case with most of those books...

Comment: @Barmar, thank you so much for your explanation, which made it really clear why I was confused. This is the first case where I see the modes changing in the same sentence (at least that I am aware of) . The subjunctive mode is sometimes really confusing.

Comment: Subjunctive can be confusing to many people, and it's often avoided.